# Java need help Deserializing multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I'm writing a module which serializes others and I've got everything working only I'm unsure of how I should deserialize multidimensional arrays.

The problem is, I need to deserialize something like this(There are other attributes for each node, such as the objects SUID, that I've excluded for simplicity's sake.)

```
<var object="[[I">
    <_0 object="[I">
        <_0 object="java.lang.Integer">1</_0>
        <_1 object="java.lang.Integer">2</_1>
    </_0>
    <_1 object="[I">
        <_0 object="java.lang.Integer">3</_0>
        <_1 object="java.lang.Integer">4</_1>
    </_1>
</var>
```

Where the "object" attribute on each node describes what object it is. If it is an array of a primitive type, it will begin with an array of `[` brackets, where each one represents a count in its depth. I.e:

```
type int[][] = [[I

type int[] = [i
```

The problem is I don't know how I'd programatically create an array with a depth of x? I.e, if I had to do it my way it would probably be something like:

```
switch(iArrayDepth)
{
    case 1:
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    case 2:
        return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    case 3:
        return new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
etc...
}
```

There must be a better way of doing it :S

Another problem arises when I need to unbox this array and make it a mutlidimensional array of a primitive type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is not an array. Generics have type erasure at runtime so what you are trying to with the switch is meaningless at runtime.

If you want to create a List just create it without generics.

```
List list = new ArraysList();
```

If you want to create an array of a specific type you can use Arrays.

```
Object array = Arrays.newArray(arrayType, arrayDepth);
```

I would rethink your file format. Its verbose for the amount of data you are conveying.

how about something like

```
int[[ 2
1,2
3,4
```

This conveys the same information in a much more compact format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array whose type and dimensionality are not known at compile time using [`Array.newInstance(Class, int...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29).  For example, the following create an 3 x 4 x 5 array of `int`.

```
Object array = Array.instance(Integer.CLASS, 3, 4, 5);
```

or

```
Object array = Array.instance(Integer.CLASS, new int[]{3, 4, 5});
```

This solves the second part of your question as well.